# How do sync a tree of photos in Darktable so it picks up additions/deletions?

Tags: darktable

I am new to Darktable and trying to use it to manage a large tree of RAW images.

I've recursively imported the root of the tree already. It's now displaying the directory names in the lighttable view when I select "folders" on the left under "collect images".

If I now add more images to the existing directories or add new directories under the root, or remove some images, how do I tell DarkTable to scan the root directory again and have it pick up the additions or deletions?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely import the root directory again, Darktable will skip the pictures already imported. AFAIK there's no way to somehow automate the import process.